# Fotorama and Shadowbox aren't working together properly

Tags: jquery, html, image-gallery, shadowbox, fotorama

I have shadowbox operating for my pictures underneath the fotorama gallery, and it is working great. However, when I click on any button on the fotorama gallery it immediately brings up a shadowbox of an image. I can't figure out why it keeps popping up with a shadowbox image when all i want to do is change to another fotorama pic. Here is the website which show exactly what the problem is:

http://ultimatefinishdetailing.com/TiburonPictures.html

Here is the code on the website:

HTML Page Head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
});
</script>
```

HTML for the fotorama:

```
<script>
fotoramaDefaults = {
width: 700,
maxwidth: '100%',
ratio: 16/9,
allowfullscreen: true,
nav: 'thumbs'
}
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link  href="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.4.9/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.4.9/fotorama.js"></script>
<div class="fotorama">
<img src="images/IMG00242-20110527-17513.jpg">
<img src="images/IMG00248-20110527-17522.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fotorama and Shadowbox are not working correctly together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109321/fotorama-and-shadowbox-are-not-working-correctly-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a link issue on one of the shadowbox pictures. I erased one of the html picture links and made a new one. Fixed! If you have the same problem. Erase all picture links to make sure it is actually the link itself. Then, its process of elimination.